# Using MATERIALIZED VIEW in Cassandra gives error

Tags: cassandra

I have following table.

```
CREATE TABLE test_x (id text PRIMARY KEY, type frozen<mycustomtype>);
```

mycustomtype is defined as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE mycustomtype (
   id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
   name text
 )
```

And i have created following materialized view for queries based on mycustometype filed.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_x_by_mycustomtype_name AS
   SELECT id, type
   FROM test_x
   WHERE type IS NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (id, type)
   WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (type ASC)
```

With above view i hope to execute following query.

```
select id from test_x_by_mycustomtype_name where type =
{id: a3e64f8f-bd44-4f28-b8d9-6938726e34d4,  name: 'Sample'};
```

But the query fails saying i need to use 'ALLOW FILTERING'. I created the view not to use ALLOW FILTERING. Why this error is happening here since i have used the part of primary key of the view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you view, the `type` column is still clustering key. Hence, ALLOW FILTER should be used. You can change the view as per below and retry

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_x_by_mycustomtype_name_2 AS
   SELECT id, type
   FROM test_x
   WHERE type IS NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (type, id)
   WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC);
```

```
cqlsh:test> select id from test_x_by_mycustomtype_name_2 where type = {id: a3e64f8f-bd44-4f28-b8d9-6938726e34d4,  name: 'Sample'};

id
----
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change the order of the primary key of materialized view**

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_x_by_mycustomtype_name AS
   SELECT id, type
   FROM test_x
   WHERE type IS NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (type, id)
   WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (type ASC);
```